# Predicate where condition is not working in IQueryable but working after converted IQueryable to ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, filter, iqueryable

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Items>(true);
predicate = predicate.Or(i => Convert.ToDateTime(i.Entrydate).ToString("M/d/yyyy").Contains(searchText));`
```

`Entrydate` is `DateTime?` type so directly I can't able to use `.ToString('M/d/yyyy')` string format.

This is not working (exception : `Must be reducible node`)

```
IQueryable<Items> items = Repository.GetItems(orderNo).Where(predicate);
```

This is working

```
IQueryable<Items> items = Repository.GetItems(orderNo).ToList().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
```

But I don't want to convert the results to list while these are in `IQueryable`

Please note: I am using `Convert.ToDateTime()` method in **predicate (dynamic) where** condition

Comment: Hi! Add your predicate, so we could see what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working'? Is there an error? If so, what is it? And what is `predicate`?

Comment: What means "not working" ? An Error message?
In NHibernate ORM there was queries that the ORM couldn't map to SQL query because of it's complexity.

Comment: Something in the predicate code requires the List.  You probably need to change a variable definition in the predicate from List<> to var. You also need to change the return type.  Note you cannot return a var object you have to cast return item to var.

Comment: `AsQueryable` should be removed - it is very rarely useful.

Comment: Please always include full exception messages. You get a `NotSupportedException`, because `Convert.ToDateTime()` can't be translated into SQL. You should look for an alternative that can be translated. Why do you need the conversion anyway?

Comment: Hi I have been added predicate code and exception so that you can find it out.

Comment: I need to use `Convert.ToDateTime()` because the datatype i have is `DateTime?`. So that in this type of datatype i can't able to use `.ToString("M/d/yyyy")` format.

Comment: Please share some example values of `searchText`.

Comment: Neither `Convert` nor `ToString(format)` are supported by EF SQL query translator. Btw, `Must be reducible node` exception sounds like EF **Core**, is that correct? If yes, it's good to include such information in the question and tags. Also the version.

Comment: `searchText` may be `searchText = "2/"`,  `searchText = "2/2/20"` etc

Answer (score 2):

So you have a class Items, with a DateTime? property EntryDate. And you need as input for your predicate builder an `Expression> that represents a predicate that returns true if the string representation of Items.EntryDate contains some searchText.

In other words, if EntryDate equals "23 december 2003", then its string representation is "12/25/2003" and you want to return true if this contains searchText.

Alas you didn't specify what you want if EntryDate is null. I assume you want to return false.

```
Expression<Func<Items, bool>> predicate = (items.EntryDate != null)
   && (items.EntryDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy").Contains(searchText));
```

You can use this in your PredicateBuilder.

By the way: I think it is not wise to compare textual representations of DateTime. This is way to Culture dependent.